# Uploading LFS objects - Repository or object not found

Tags: git-lfs

I've used git sparingly in the past and am new to setting up my own private git server.  After weeks of no luck using SSH now I'm onto HTTP.  I can push git files but not LFS files.  I'm clearly missing something.  Any tips?

```
$ git lfs env
git-lfs/2.9.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.5)
git version 2.25.1

LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=/var/www/git/test.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/var/www/git/test.git
LocalMediaDir=/var/www/git/test.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/var/www/git/test.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/var/www/git/test.git/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/usr/lib/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Client-side

```
$ git lfs env
git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.2; git 48b28d97)
git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Endpoint=https://username@hostname/git/test.git/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=C:\gitlab\test
LocalGitDir=C:\gitlab\test\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\gitlab\test\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\gitlab\test\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=C:\gitlab\test\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=C:\gitlab\test\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

I have a fresh git repo named test.git and I've run "git lfs install" inside it's folder to update the git hooks.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
17:32:09.406762 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
17:32:09.411265 git.c:444               trace: built-in: git push origin master
17:32:09.415267 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:09.437282 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:09.441284 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:09.441284 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:09.471303 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:13.682739 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
17:32:13.812317 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:13.816320 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
17:32:13.816320 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get
17:32:14.108703 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager store'
17:32:14.197258 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:14.201760 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-credential-manager store
17:32:14.202260 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager store
17:32:14.474436 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: .git/hooks/pre-push origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:14.609023 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:14.613526 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-lfs pre-push origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:14.613526 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-lfs pre-push origin https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:14.682070 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
17:32:14.794642 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
17:32:14.994769 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '-l'
17:32:15.030791 trace git-lfs: pre-push: refs/heads/master 17a92bf0a4ae09390b6f79dcbc3de51fd6de8ca9 refs/heads/master 28eef8c2f228b36daaae1d5b3c21695e44cb8471
17:32:16.027315 trace git-lfs: tq: running as batched queue, batch size of 100
17:32:16.027815 trace git-lfs: run_command: git rev-list --objects --ignore-missing --not --remotes=origin --stdin --
17:32:16.121374 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 1
17:32:16.121875 trace git-lfs: api: batch 1 files
17:32:16.121875 trace git-lfs: creds: git credential fill ("https", "hostname", "")
17:32:16.145390 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:16.150393 git.c:444               trace: built-in: git credential fill
17:32:16.151894 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
17:32:16.254460 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
17:32:16.260964 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
17:32:16.260964 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get
17:32:16.611189 trace git-lfs: Filled credentials for https://username@hostname/git/test.git
17:32:16.611189 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST https://username@hostname/git/test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
17:32:16.633203 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 404
17:32:16.633203 trace git-lfs: api error: Repository or object not found: https://username@hostname/git/test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
batch response: Repository or object not found: https://username@hostname/git/test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://hostname/git/test.git'
```